# Check if specific column is greater than another column and create a new column based on condition in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with variables as ID, other variables I have grouped them into list
as shown below:

```
CYCLE_BALANCE =['BILL_BAL_01',  'BILL_BAL_02',  'BILL_BAL_03',  'BILL_BAL_04',
                'BILL_BAL_05',  'BILL_BAL_06'] 


CASH_BALANCE = ['BILL_CASH_BAL_01', 'BILL_CASH_BAL_02', 'BILL_CASH_BAL_03', 
                'BILL_CASH_BAL_04', 'BILL_CASH_BAL_05', 'BILL_CASH_BAL_06']
```

I want to check below condition and calculate the count in new column as below:

```
for index in dqc_data1.iterrows():
    for i in CYCLE_BALANCE:
        for j in CASH_BALANCE:
            count = 0
            if dqc_data1.loc[i]> dqc_data1.loc[j]:
                dqc_data1['count1'] = count + 1
```

In single row it should check corresponding variables and as the condition satisfied count should increment. Thank you

Comment: You must provide a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

use a dataframe transform and a lambda function instead of iloc.  transforms apply logic to every row in the dataframe and assign the results to a dataframe column